# "TL:DR:" In Job Title

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

What is the "TL:DR" in the job title of [this job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/135311/tl-dr-senior-front-end-developer-impact-our-catawiki)?
Similar job title [here](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/118297/tl-dr-senior-back-end-developer-impact-our-catawiki) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/131415/tl-dr-senior-security-analyst-keeping-our-catawiki)

Comment: [Too Long: Didn't Read;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read) = Short Summary.

Comment: Too Long Didn't read what ?

Comment: The job description, Roles and Responsibilities, etc.

Comment: See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR

Comment: Arguably a bad title, agreed, but not a bug.

Comment: To cut a long story short is basically what it means. In a title this is pointless as a title should do exactly that by definition.

Comment: ... and it's even written wrong: it has a colon instead of a semicolon.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Shame, shame, shame...

Comment: @Seth http://shamenun.com

Comment: @DeanWard since it's a company whose name ends in wiki it could be a cunning plan to filter applicants just using the first word of the title :-P

Comment: @Pekka웃 Didn't know of that site till now... Thanks for sharing :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this was intentional on the employer's part. They appear to be getting success with their listings so it's their call whether they change it or not. Their sales rep will reach out to them to see whether that's the case.